# Best tool or solutions for GUI in desktop app using Java SE

Tags: java, user-interface, desktop

For a normal GUI (desktop) application with standard controls, like labels, textbox, progress bars, buttons, panels and so on, do you believe that what is the most suitable solution or tool  to make easy and less painfully the development of a GUI applications using J2SE in the following suggestions:

- Use Layout Manager like JGoodies, Mig Layout
- Use Matisse Editor on NetBeans
- Use Netbeans Plataform
- Use Java FX
- Use Merapi (for air/flex approach)

What your your opinion?

Also I love this site and this community!

Comment: Having worked with Matisse for a couple of years, I can tell you that using a GUI builder does not preclude judicious use of layout managers. I don't know about the other form design tools, but Matisse's "Free design" mode used to generate copious amounts of GUI construction code and the components never stayed in place when resizing the form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Mig Layout as a LayoutManger AND use [WindowBuilder](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html) with Eclipse as a GUI designer. WB really rocks!

One of the nice things about WindowBuilder is the fact that it doesn't generate extra .form files or other stuff. Just plain java classes with pretty clean code I might add :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed using Groovy then [SwingBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Swing+Builder) is a perfect tool.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans itself can help you alot without the use of external libraries, just create a JFrame class, then drag-and-drop JComponents to the Frame